# PhantomJS Selenium Common.LocalForage:IndexedDB is NOT available

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to create a way of scraping data from TradingView.com. They do not provide an API and there are limited Python projects trying to scrape this data.

I have implemented the code below.

1. Load the page.
2. Take a screenshot (Page data is not loaded)
3. Wait for a span containing the date to be populated.
4. Take another screenshot (Page data SHOULD be loaded)

The class names have randomly generated suffixes when they are finally populated, and my Selenium-fu is not good enough yet to find partial class names and awaiting them. It is easier to test the span containing the date as a signal that the page has loaded.

https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-GOOGL/technicals/

```
url = "https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-GOOGL/technicals/"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(url) 
driver.save_screenshot("1.png")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_element_by_class_name("js-symbol-lp-time").text)>0) 
driver.save_screenshot("2.png")
```

Both screenshots show the uninitialised page.

The logs for the browser can be printed.

```
    for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
        print(entry)
```

This is the warning, but i can understand why it may be problematic. So i think the page is erroring as IndexDB is not available.

```
{u'timestamp': 1589730715971, u'message': u'2020-05-17T15:51:55.971Z:Common.LocalForage:IndexedDB is NOT available\n  c (https://www.tradingview.com/static/bundles/category.efc811b3c9028b9b2156.js:286)', u'level': u'WARNING'}
```

Any thoughts?

Regards

The output of the second screenshot. Even the Stock title and other static data is not available which suggests it is breaking before fetching the variable data. 
[image]

Comment: Why are you using PhantomJS? PhantomJS development was halted long ago. Please try with another browser like headless chrome.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have followed up on what you have said and tried again. The same issue appears when running with https://chromedriver.chromium.org/ Do you suggest any other resources? I am on MacOS.

Comment: Your screenshot suggests it is opening on a mobile resolution. That may be the issue. Please increase resolution and then see.